# Devide js application in build time composable parts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, webpack, rollup

Let's say we have a js application (React, Vue, Vanilla or whatever) bundled with Rollup, Parcel, Webpack or whatever. It consists of logical modules A, B, C, D, and is delivered to client as one bundle.

Now we need to prepare application for white labeling.
Every white label customer needs only a partial set of logical modules, e.g. Customer1 needs A, B, and D, Customer2 only A and B, Customer 3 - A, B, C, and D.

The obvious way to connect this logical parts is import them in some root file as ES modules separately for every customer, but this means lots of manual work before every deploy.

So the question is... Is there any way to automate this process in build time? So we could just do `yarn run build customer1` before deploy, and it would read some config file and compose only needed modules together.

Forgot to mention the app is a PWA with some offline functionality, so dynamic import is not an option, all its modules must be loaded on startup.

Comment: I think you could accomplish this by creating a custom webpack loader and various webpack config file to config the loader based on customer.

Comment: @JohnnyZabala okay, but what should this loader do?
The only thing I come up with is commenting out the corresponding lines of code, e.g. `// import moduleC from 'modules/C'` before bundling

Comment: I think the custom loader I proposed was already create: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/null-loader.